# Add a new column with tag attached to crescent numbers

Tags: r, tags, numbers

I would like to add a new collumn giving a constant tag with anexed with a crescent numbers logic, line after line.

My input:

```
position  work  

chr1    jil2001
chr4    jil2001
chr3    kou2009
chr9    nai2012
chr7    fandis2005
```

My expected output:

```
position  work    tag

chr1    jil2001  Known1
chr4    jil2001  Known2
chr3    kou2009  Known3
chr9    nai2012  Known4
chr7    fan2005  Known5
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create the new column manually;

```
df$tag <- paste0("Known", seq_len(nrow(df)))
```